# Spacetime from Entanglement

Tags: spacetime, quantum-entanglement

I have come across several articles on the net which talk about constructing spacetime from entanglement.
However, the AdS/CFT correspondence is always mentioned in this context.
So is the idea that spacetime can be constructed from entanglement only applicable to the AdS spacetime or does it hold in general? Are there any reasons to believe that this is also applicable to general spacetime?

Comment: Are you aware of the [ER=EPR proposal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ER%3DEPR)? The Wikipedia article lists several references.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly No I wasn't aware of it. I am checking the references now.